# Why is AutoFilter being applied three rows before the specified range

Tags: excel, vba

The following code applies autofilter to several worksheets from date criteria set in worksheet "'Grand Totals'!B1", applying to worksheet range A6, which is formatted as date.  Rows 1-5 contain headers and formulae. But, rows 3-5 are disappearing along with the filtered rows beginning in A6. Can anyone see why? According to what I know, everything above row A6 should remain visible. Thanks again for your help.

Sub ApplyFilterDate()

```
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turn off ScreenUpdating to speed filtering
        For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Ws.Name <> "Grand Totals" Then
                Ws.Activate
                Ws.AutoFilterMode = False 'Remove any existing filters
                Ws.Range("A6").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("'Grand Totals'!B1").Text
                Range("G2").Activate
                Center_it 'Puts next data entry cell in approximate center of screen
            End If
        Next
    Sheet1.Activate
    Range("B2").ClearContents
    Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Set color of cell showing filter date
    Range("B1").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turn on ScreenUpdating
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the Autofilter to operate on cell A6 only. This doesn't make sense, so Excel expands the selection to include surrounding cells. You need to specify the range on which to apply the autofilter.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had looked at several examples and many had only the first cell in a column referenced so I thought perhaps that was enough. Boy, I've got a lot to learn! The Field argument is used to select the column you want to filter by if your range is more than 1 column wide?

Comment: Excel VBA is not the simplest of object models. My advice is get to know the **Range** object and think twice before accepting unchanged what the macro recorder gives you. Yes, you're correct about the *Field* parameter. Please would you accept my answer by clicking on the tick *if* you think it's better than the other one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following syntax to avoid your problem:

```
Ws.Range("A6:e6").AutoFilter '... and so on with exact range address
```